# how to separate mixed email ids from cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

how to separate mixed email ids from cell range like

in column A all email ids are mixed with hyperlink i want to separate them each every single cell

```
Column A
krish@gmail.com hanu@gmail.com pradeep@gmail.com anish@gmail.com
```

i want to separate the mixed email ids to separate cell with hyperlink like this below mention

```
Column A
krish@gmail.com
hanu@gmail.com
pradeep@gmail.com
anish@gmail.com
```

Comment: Look in VBA documentation for `Split` function.

Comment: what version of Excel are you using?

Comment: My Excel version 2016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a general purpose formula for extracting the email addresses contained in column A into separate cells (eg B1,C1 etc).

Copied down/across as required.

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(" "&$A1&" "," ",REPT(" ",40)),FIND(REPT("@",COLUMNS($A1:A1)),SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(" "&$A1&" "," ",REPT(" ",40)),"@",REPT("@",COLUMNS($A1:A1)),COLUMNS($A1:A1)))-40,80))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

VBA is probably the quickest, but here's an alternative method w/out VBA. First, highlight your column A and go to Data...Text to Columns... Delimited... By Space. That will input each email address into their own cell.

Then insert an extra column to the left. So, column A is just a blank column.

Then create a pivot table (not in the usual fashion), by pressing ALT-D then P. Select "Multiple Consolidation Ranges" in the wizard's first window. Press Next.

Then select "Create a single page field for me" in the wizard, and press Next.

Then select your range (including the blank column). In this case, our range is A1:E4. Add that range, press Next.

Place the pivot into a new worksheet (or existing, your choice) and press FINISH.

Design your pivot by placing the "Value" field in the row area. Then filter to remove "blank" and change the design to remove Grand Total.

Now you have all emails stacked atop each other. If you want to create another column to retain their link, then you could add this as column B formula:

```
=HYPERLINK(A4,A4)
```

**ORIGINAL DATA:**
[image]

**HOW IT LOOKS AFTER DELIMITING AND ADDING A BLANK COLUMN:**
[image]

**FINAL OUTPUT OF PIVOT AND OPTIONAL COLUMN B AS HYPERLINK:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Excel 365, in **B1** insert:

```
=parsee(TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,A:A)," ")
```

where `parsee()` is this UDF:

```
Option Explicit
Public Function parsee(inpt As String, sep As String)
'
'   spill-down version
'
    Dim L As Long, i As Long, temp, arr
    Dim lb As Long, ub As Long
    
    If inpt = "" Then
        parsee = ""
        Exit Function
    End If
    If sep = "" Then
        L = Len(inpt)
        ReDim arr(1 To L, 1 To 1)
        For i = 1 To L
            arr(i, 1) = Mid(inpt, i, 1)
        Next i
    Else
        temp = Split(inpt, sep)
        lb = LBound(temp)
        ub = UBound(temp)
        ReDim arr(lb To ub, 1 To 1)
        For i = lb To ub
            arr(i, 1) = temp(i)
        Next i
    End If
    parsee = arr
End Function
```

Comment: My office version is 2016 & i have applied ur UDF on my sheet to separate mixed email ids with hyperlink i have getting value error like #Value i have applied UDF Function like =parsee(A1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use FILTERXML formula to split emails. In Office 365, a typical formula would be :

`=FILTERXML("<t><d>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</d><d>")&"</d></t>","//d")`

where `A1` holds the input string you have posted.